# How to configure Merge Strategies on Bitbucket Cloud?

Tags: git, bitbucket, pull-request, branching-strategy

I want to configure BitBucket Cloud so that Pull Requests won't create merge commits but rather only do fast forward merges.

However, I can't seem to find a way to configure this. For Bitbucket Server there seems to be an easy way to do this: http://blogs.atlassian.com/2016/08/new-features-bitbucket-4-9/

Any ideas on how to achieve the same thing with Bitbucket Cloud?

Comment: All i can find is 
" Tim Pettersen ATLASSIAN TEAM Feb 05, 2017
...
You're correct. Sorry for the confusion. There are variances in the feature set offered by the Cloud and Server versions of Bitbucket, and in this case Server is slightly ahead of Cloud in terms of functionality. For now, Bitbucket Cloud currently supports only a subset of the merge strategies available in Bitbucket Server. 
 cheers, Tim " https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/See-all-5-Pull-request-merge-strategies-in-Bitbucket-Cloud/qaq-p/324751#M11369

Answer (score 2):

There's a feature request thread going that would allow fast-forward commits from the Pull Request. I know this is not the full answer to your question, but it's part of it. If you'd like to see this feature implemented, vote on the issue. 
[Provide the option to use "git merge --ff-only" for pull requests](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/6106/provide-the-option-to-use-git-merge-ff)

Answer (score 2):

Capability exists in BitBucket Cloud on the repository's merge strategy in settings.

[image]

Which has this description:

> Select Fast forward if the destination branch has no new commits since
>   you created the source branch. Fast-forward merges move the source
>   branch tip up to the destination branch tip, combining commit
>   histories. Because this strategy moves the source branch's commits to
>   the destination branch, you'll still see all commits on the Commits
>   page.

Comment: in 2024, the above options are still the only ones - if you want to fast forward + squash, you're still out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

According to this thread this feature (merge strategy selection) was implemented only for Bitbucket Server product:

https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/8995/provide-the-option-to-use-git-merge-squash

Some people asked about Bitbucket Cloud but no staff member replied back :(